# PowerShell is running multiple commands to activate conda base environment

Tags: python, powershell, anaconda

When I run the PowerShell built-in on VScode, it fires the command `C:/Users/yurim/anaconda3/activate` by default every time I open VScode and returns an error afterwards.

The output of the command `C:/Users/yurim/anaconda3/activate` (some text is provided in portuguese):

```
C:/Users/yurim/anaconda3/activate : O termo 'C:/Users/yurim/anaconda3/activate' não é reconhecido como nome de cmdlet, função, arquivo de script ou programa operável.
Verifique a grafia do nome ou, se um caminho tiver sido incluído, veja se o caminho está correto e tente novamente.
No linha:1 caractere:1
+ C:/Users/yurim/anaconda3/activate
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:/Users/yurim/anaconda3/activate:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

This command is also being fired on the Python terminal upon initialization.

I think it is trying to activate the anaconda base environment but it fails with this default command. Immediately after the previous command PowerShell runs the following `conda activate C:\Users\yurim\anaconda3\envs\ppgep` which is my custom environment (one that I created) and successfully activates it. As a result, I am unable to access my base environment without manually activating it. I have been running PowerShell as my default terminal on VScode.

I noticed the initial command is being launched with the backslash inverted, so it does not reference the actual directory, but I don't no why in the first place this command is being fired.

I installed anaconda and have run `conda init` on Anaconda PowerShell.

I have also set the variable path to my environment variables as `C:\Users\yurim\anaconda3` and doubled check with `conda info` that this is the correct env location of my conda base env.

I had tried to update the anaconda package using `conda update anaconda` and this came out:

```
PackageNotInstalledError: Package is not installed in prefix.
  prefix: C:\Users\yurim\anaconda3
  package name: anaconda
```

I think it may be a clue to what causing the command `C:/Users/yurim/anaconda3/activate` to be fired. Another thing to add up to this, my shortcut to launch the Anaconda Navigator does not work, so the installation directory may have been changed somehow.

Instead I launched Anaconda PowerShell and ran the command `conda update --name conda base`

It worked and now I am running the latest version of anaconda. But,as for the command `C:/Users/yurim/anaconda3/activate` is still being fired on PowerShell every time I open VScode.

How can solve this issue? What is the root cause of this?